# Creating mySQLi Prepared Statements for a PHP User Class

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a User class that I created which looks something like this:

```
class User {
    private $user;
    private $con;

    public function __construct($con, $user){
        $this->con = $con;
        $user_details_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
        $this->user = mysqli_fetch_array($user_details_query);
    }

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->user['username'];
    }

    public function getNumberOfFriendRequests() {
        $username = $this->user['username'];
        $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE user_to='$username'");
        return mysqli_num_rows($query);
    }

    public function getNumPosts() {
        $username = $this->user['username'];
        $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT num_posts FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        return $row['num_posts'];
    }
```

There is much more to this, however what I'm trying to understand is how to re-create it using prepared statements without messing up the rest of the pages.  I have calls over several pages that rely on the given User class contstruct.  I'm new to prepared staements but have managed to do pretty well, however am having trouble when it comes to the classes. I trying to recreate for example `public function getNumberOfFriendRequests()` so that it has the same output as before, so that existing pages are not throwing errors.  Here is what I have so far:

```
public function getNumberOfFriendRequests() {
$username $this->user['username'];
$query = mysqli_prepare($this->$con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friend_requests WHERE user_to=?");
$query->bind_param('s', $username);
$query->execute();
$query_>bind_result(NOT SURE);
$query->fetch();
}
```

I'm also confused abt the `public function __construct($con, $user)` because this is what is called whenever I want to access the User data.  Does anyone know how I would begin to rewrite the given User class so that the returns are the same & not interfering with php calls on dependent pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your same class rewritten to use prepared statements.  Your construct makes sense as you're saying "This User" and also passing in your DB object.  You won't use bind_result, as you're using SELECT *, and bind_result is for targeting specific fields.

```
class User {
private $user;
private $con;

public function __construct($con, $user){
    $this->con = $con;

    /* prepare the query */
    $stmt =  $this->con->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');

    /* Bind to string $user */
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Get a result obj */
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $this->user = $result->fetch_assoc();

    /* free results */
    $stmt->free_result();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

public function getUsername() {
    return $this->user['username'];
}

public function getNumberOfFriendRequests() {
    $username = $this->user['username'];
    $stmt =  $this->con->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare('SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE user_to = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Get a result obj */
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $qty = $result->num_rows;

    /* free results */
    $stmt->free_result();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();

    return $qty;
}

public function getNumPosts() {
    $username = $this->user['username'];
    $stmt =  $this->con->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare('SELECT num_posts FROM users WHERE username=?');

    /* Bind to string $user */
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Get a result obj */
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $data = $result->fetch_assoc();

    /* free results */
    $stmt->free_result();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();

    return $data['num_posts'];
}
```

P.S. Don't use SELECT *; see: [Select * Is Evil](http://www.parseerror.com/blog/select-*-is-evil)

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm trying to understand `$stmt->free_result();` `free_result()` frees the memory associated w/ the result (b/c I google it :) but in relation to the query, what does it actually do?  Also, when you have `return $data` or `return $qty` (for example) which are different variables than what I'm returning, won't this scramble dependent pages?

Comment: In relation to the query, free_result does nothing save "erase it" from memory

My $qty is the result of `$result->num_rows`, which is essentially the same thing you're doing with your `return mysqli_num_rows($query)`.  The only difference is, I'm passing the number into that variable and then destroying the query.

Comment: My $data *is* a typo, good catch!!  It should be return $data['num_posts'] for similar reasons as my $qty above.

Comment: Ok I'll try this, however what is `public function __construct($con, $user)` returning?  My construct is returning `$user_details_query`

Comment: Your construct is *not*.  It is saving the results of the query as $this->user as I am.  A constructor typically should not return *anything* as it is the function automatically called when the class is instantiated.  so `$foo = new Bar('stuff');` would pass 'stuff' into the constructor, and then return an instance of the Bar() class into foo.

That said `$foobar = $foo->fizzbuzz();` would catch what ever the return was from the function fizzbuzz() within the Bar() class and set the variable $foobar as whatever that is.

Comment: wow, nice.  I understand & thankyou.  I learned allot from this.